# как исправить ошибку: Vector subscript out of range

Tags: c++

```
void BFS(vector<vector<int>> matrix)
{
    vector<int> temp;
    print_matrix(matrix);
    queue<int> Q;
    int am = matrix.size();
    int* visited = new int[am];
    for (int i = 0; i < am; i++)visited[i] = 0;
    int unit = 0;
    visited[unit] = 1;
    Q.push(unit);
    for (int a = 0; !Q.empty(); a++)
    {
 
        unit = Q.front();
        temp.push_back(unit);
        Q.pop();
        show_queue(Q);
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++)
            if (matrix[unit][i] && !visited[i])-Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x7B04FC66 (ucrtbased.dll) в Project1.exe: Недопустимый параметр был передан функции, для которой недопустимые параметры вызывают неустранимую ошибку.
 
            {
                Q.push(i);
                visited[i] = 1;
                show_queue(Q);
            }
    }cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << temp[i] << " ";
    }cout << endl;
    delete[]visited;
}
```

0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0

Comment: А у вас матрица `matrix` строго квадратная?... Просто `matrix.size()` - это по первому измерению, а не по второму...

Comment: добавил сверху матрицу

Comment: Не удается повторить: https://ideone.com/8pbahQ

Comment: https://ibb.co/20zyLGY у меня чего-то не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходим из вашей картинки.

Итак, матрица **НЕ** квадратная, а 13 строк и 11 столбцов. То, что я и намекал в комментарии...

Итак,

```
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++)
     if (matrix[unit][i] && !visited[i])
```

Чему равен `matrix.size()`? Это число строк - 13.

Значит, вы обращаетесь к **13** элементам вектора `matrix[unit]`. А их всего **11**.

Выход за границы диапазона, о чем вам и доложили...

Количество столбцов в строке `matrix[unit]` - не `matrix.size()`, а вовсе даже `matrix[unit].size()`...

Хотя как вы для графа используете не квадратную матрицу - мне непонятно...